# Split With Cross Apply function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I need to split a variable as, exp

```
declare @testString varchar(100)

set @testString = ' Agency=100|Org=2112|RepOrg=2112|SubOrg= |Fund=0137|Approp=6755|Object= |SubObject= |Activity= |Function= |Job= |ReportingCat= '

select 
    y.items 
from 
    dbo.Split(@testString, '|') x 
cross apply 
    dbo.Split(x.items, '=') y
```

Leads to error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Seems like dbo.Split is a UDF, I'm assuming similar to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb2b2421-6587-4956-aff0-a7df9c91a84a/what-is-dbosplit?forum=transactsql if so, I ran that and your query worked. You might need to track down the definition of your version of Split and include it.

Comment: If I run single query without cross apply it ran, but not together

Comment: Is this some UDF dbo.split ? What version of SQL server it is ?

Comment: @Avi not sure about udf split, just needed this functionality.

Comment: You need to track down the definition of Split. What you have there works for a random definition of split that I found and implemented, so it's more likely related to your specific implementation.

Comment: @DeepakDhaka Please check my answer to see if that is your expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same function which you have used dbo.split. To get the output (Agency in one column and code in another), you can make use of substring along with char index which will help you to split into two columns.

Few changes I made to your script: 
  Changed the length from 100 to 250 as it was truncating the string, and 
  removed another cross apply as it was creating duplicates.

```
declare @testString varchar(250)
set @testString = 'Agency=100|Org=2112|RepOrg=2112|SubOrg= 
|Fund=0137|Approp=6755|Object= |SubObject= |Activity= |Function= |Job= |ReportingCat='

select substring( (x.items),1, 
case when  CHARINDEX('=',  x.items) = 0 then LEN(x.items) 
 else CHARINDEX('=', x.items) -1 end ) Agency ,   
 substring( (x.items),  
 case when  CHARINDEX('=',  x.items) = 0 then LEN(x.items) 
 else CHARINDEX('=', x.items) +1 end,len(x.items) -
 case when  CHARINDEX('=',  x.items) = 0 then LEN(x.items)  
  else CHARINDEX('=', x.items)-1  end) as Code   from dbo.split 
  (@testString, '|') x
```

It ran without error, and that function is here as Ben mentioned. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb2b2421-6587-4956-aff0-a7df9c91a84a/what-is-dbosplit?forum=transactsql

Output which I get:

```
  Agency    Code
  Agency    100
  Org       2112
  RepOrg    2112
  SubOrg        
  Fund      0137
  Approp    6755
  Object     
  SubObject  
  Activity   
  Function   
  Job    
  ReportingCat
```

Comment: I missed , I need Data such way like, agency in one column and it's corresponding code in other

Comment: Updated the query to fetch y.items

Comment: @DeepakDhaka Updated the query to get the expected output, please check.

Comment: Thanks it worked, there must be some issue with split method in version.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need something like this:-

[image]

```
DECLARE @testString VARCHAR(100)

SET @testString = 
    ' Agency=100|Org=2112|RepOrg=2112|SubOrg= |Fund=0137|Approp=6755|Object= |SubObject= |Activity= |Function= |Job= |ReportingCat= '

SELECT X.VALUE  AS ACTUALVALUE,
       SUBSTRING(
           X.VALUE,
           1,
           CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('=', X.VALUE) = 0 THEN LEN(X.VALUE)
                ELSE CHARINDEX('=', X.VALUE) -1
           END
       )                                 AS FIELD,
       SUBSTRING(X.VALUE, CHARINDEX('=', X.VALUE) + 1, 10) AS VALUE
FROM   string_split(@testString, '|') x
```